# how to create two labels side by side using javascript

Tags: javascript, cordova

my requirement is create two labels side by side using javascript. I used this code for one label, i need another label to the right of first label.

```
My Code is here

var label = document.createElement('label');
        label.innerHTML = "Hi";
            document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
            label.addEventListener("click", onClick);
            document.body.appendChild(label);

I want to create another label to the right of above one. Help me
```

Comment: You should learn about the web technology CSS http://www.w3schools.com/css/ this allows you to style web UIs

Comment: @ColinE you are including `w3fools.com` in your comment.

Comment: @AspiringAqib I've just visited w3fools - I see your point. I'll no longer share links to w3schools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
var label = document.createElement('label');
var label2 = document.createElement('label');
label.innerHTML = "Hi";
label2.innerHTML = "How are you?";
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
document.body.appendChild(label);
document.body.appendChild(label2);
```

**Update1:**

```
function f1(){

var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = "Hi";
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    document.body.appendChild(label);
}
function f2(){
    var label2 = document.createElement('label');
    label2.innerHTML = "How are you???";
    document.body.appendChild(label2);
}
```

**Update2**

```
function f1(){
var a = new Array ( "Hi", "How are you?", "i am fine?");
var label = document.createElement('label');
    label.innerHTML = a;
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    document.body.appendChild(label);
}
function f2(){
    var label2 = document.createElement('label');
    label2.innerHTML = "How are you???";
    document.body.appendChild(label2);
}
```

Comment: thanx for ur code, but my requirement is to print first label data from one function, and print second label in another function

Comment: @Madhavi so what problem you are facing while printing values from array,please post your code, and i would suggest you to put your code in the same question, or start a new question.

Comment: @Madhavi are you able to `print values from array`?

Answer (score 1):

You also have appended `<br>` elements before the label is appended which enforces it to be on next line.

Labels are inline-elements so they do not need `display` property.